# ASP.NET MVC Form POST from Shared View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

~/Views/_TopNavigation.cshtml:

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.DropDownList("SelectionId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
</form>
```

~/Controllers/BaseController.cs

```
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        // SelectionIdlogic here
    }
```

Instead of posting to "/", I'd like the page to be routed to the current controller / action, while processing the new SelectionId value.

Comment: I don't know why @usingHtml.BeginForm(<actionName>,<controllername>,...) is not a good solution to you , you can use it to route the post to any action in any controller

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{}
```

This will post the form to the action corresponding to the `POST` action of the current view.

Comment: The problem is that if I'm on "events/add", I don't want to POST to the add method in events controller.

Answer (score -1):

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.DropDownList("SelectionId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining myself correctly. If I POSTed to the current Action / Controller, I'd have unexpected behavior. If I POSTed to a globally fixed Action / Controller, how would I redirect after processing to the current View?

Comment: You could maybe store the current view name as a hidden field and then in your controller call return View("viewname");